# Writing a better deploy script

Tags: bash

This is a script I've written to deploy the Elastic Stack.

Can you help me improve it? Especially the parts called out with `***` markings.

`deploy.sh`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
#use the elastic utility to gen certs
docker-compose -f create-certs.yml run --rm create_certs
# Start the stack initially per Elastic documentation
docker-compose up -d
#run a password gen script to make some passwords
docker exec elasticsearch /bin/bash -c "bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords \
auto --batch \
--url https://elasticsearch:9200" | tee es_passes.txt
#sub generated kibana and es passes into .env -> *** This could be better ***
cat es_passes.txt  | grep 'PASSWORD kibana' | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I {} sed -r -i 's/(KIBANA_PASS=)\w/\1{}/gip' .env
cat es_passes.txt  | grep 'PASSWORD elastic' | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I {} sed -r -i 's/(ES_PASS=)\w/\1{}/gip' .env
#eliminate duplicate lines -> *** How can I do this better ***
awk '!seen[$0]++' .env > .env_dedup
mv .env_dedup .env
#show the contents of .env
cat .env
#restart the stack after setting the passwords
docker-compose stop
docker-compose up -d
```

`.env`:

```
KIBANA_PASS=some_supersecure_kibana_pass
ES_PASS=some_supersecure_elasticsearch_pass
```

other files:

- `docker-compose.yml`
- `create-certs.yml`

---

update:
I have fixed the substitution lines. They now read:

```bsh
cat es_passes.txt  | grep 'PASSWORD kibana' | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I {} sed -r -i 's/^KIBANA_PASS=.*$/KIBANA_PASS={}/' .env
cat es_passes.txt  | grep 'PASSWORD elastic' | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I {} sed -r -i 's/^ES_PASS=.*$/ES_PASS={}/' .env
```

Comment: (Down-voters please comment.) You are right: "the `cat|grep|awk|sed` pipes" leave ample room for improvement. Let me add security concerns.

Comment: Not only is this deploy script piping everything here and there and saving passwords to plaintext files in the dir where it is deployed(!), it is also not functional :( The `.env` currently does not substitute the old password with the new completely.
I end up with:
```
KIBANA_PASS=newly_genned_passsome_supersecure_kibana_pass
ES_PASS=newly_genned_passsome_supersecure_elasticseach_pass
```
Fixing that now...

Comment: Please don't update the code in your question after answers come in. Feel free to ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shots from the hip, three decades since I seriously *programmed* shell notwithstanding:

- document your code - in the code.
  The comments presented are a good start - in the middle, irritatingly.
  What is the whole script useful for, how shall it be used?
  You can even have *executable comments*:
  if called incorrectly or with `-h`, `--help` (or even `-?`), print a
  `Usage:` to "standard error output"/file descriptor 2
  Then there are things left open:
  Why `tee` to `es_passes.txt` instead of redirect, have `sed` `p`rint the pattern space?  (I read *Spanish*_passes at first - the reason why in the following comment `es` may be as appropriate as `elastic` needed horizontal scrolling)
- with security related artefacts, assess security implications
- choose the right tool
  this does not just depend on task at hand and tools available, but on "craftsperson", too
  (Here, I might have chosen perl in the 90ies and Python in the current <strike>millenium</strike> century)
- the options and commands to `sed` speak of GNU sed
  • mention such in your question
  • consider using `--posix`
- don't use `cat | command` where `command` allows specifying input file(s)
- prefer using `awk`s *patterns* over separate filtering (e.g.,`grep`)
  (unless input is *massive*):
  `awk '/PASSWORD kibana|elastic/{print $4}' es_passes.txt …`
  (*not* convinced piping to `xargs -I` is the way to proceed.)
- the conventional "unix" way to `eliminate duplicate lines` is [uniq](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html), preceded with a `sort` where global uniqueness is necessary and altering line sequence admissible.